# Export Users' list

Tags: marketing-cloud, administration, user, data-export

Is there a way to export the list of users that we create in Marketing Cloud. I see an import option there, but don't see an export option. Either it is disabled for my account or it is not available out-of-the-box.

Please note that I do not want to export the All Subscribers' list data but only the data for the users who are created in SFMC. So, if I have 200 users in SFMC, the way it is displayed on the users section(under Administration-> Users), I need to export it as it is. And if a user is tagged to 3 BUs, I need to have three rows for that particular user, one for each BU.

Let me know how I can achieve this. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SOAP retrieve method on [AccountUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm) object to retrieve details on users currently created in Marketing Cloud.
It is not possible to export the list through the UI.

[This short guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231519&type=1) explains how to set up SoapUI to work with SFMC

Comment: Is there  a way to retrieve the details if SFMC is not integrated with Salesforce instance?

Comment: For the SOAP API to work, Salesforce connector is not a necessary prerequisite. You can use SoapUI https://www.soapui.org/ to call SFMC and retrieve the needed data. I have updated the answer with a link to a guide on how to work with SoapUI and SFMC

Comment: Have you thought about a report?

Comment: There are no standard reports being able to list all the users on the platform. You can request Salesforce to provide you with a custom report, but this is a billable task, and needs to go through their services.